# Why wine only gives me a title but not video?

Tags: windows, macos, wine, directx, winetricks

Why wine only gives me a title but not video?

I installed unofficial wineskin and tried to run a game, sounds works fine but no video there, only a title bar:
[image]

after dragging window around, window becomes black, but still no video there, sounds fine and I can click button in window but just no video:
[image]

That happens even after I installed directx dxvk in winetrick:

[image]

What can I do to fix the video?

I'm using macbook pro, big Sur, m1 chip, Wineskin-2.9.1.5, engine version 22.0.1 64bit

run log: https://docs.google.com/document/d/168nNh3UhmPULogtysacmC_niniWec5NDDDBGFweDOow/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/liberodark/bf9a80fb184a9c210222dbf4b5e09b6f and https://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik But the sounds of game works fine and I can click the button, is that just no video

Comment: Wine is not perfect and does not guarantee a full Windows experience. Use a Windows virtual machine for full compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Wine is not perfect and does not guarantee a full Windows experience.
It's especially bad when a Windows driver is required for a device,
because it doesn't support at all the installation of drivers.

Use a Windows virtual machine for full functionality.